# Auto fixing warnings reported by ScalaStyle

Tags: scala, syntax, formatting

Is there a way to get ScalaStyle (or any other automation tool) to fix some of the warnings it finds?

For example --

1. Line contains a tab (shock!!)
2. There should be a space before the plus (+) sign
3. File must end with newline character

At a stretch

1. Public method must have explicit type

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, Scalastyle does not have a way to automatically fix errors. However, it looks like [Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/users/faq) *might*. This is from their documentation:

> A scalafix “Rule” can report lint messages and provide auto-fix patches to violations of some kind of rule/coding style/convention/breaking change.

Sounds promising! I have not had a chance to use it yet, but since this question has gotten no replies in almost three years, it seemed worth adding this as a possible solution to your problem if anyone else has a similar issue.